# Codeigniter : Call div element

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hi i'm newbie in codeigniter. xD
I want to change content without refreshing all page.
my js code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
                //get input data as a array
                var post_data = {
                    'message': $("#message").val(),
                    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>ccoba/insertByajax",
                    data: post_data,
                    success: function(message) {
                        $('#input_kategori').modal('toggle');
                        //$('.first:first').after('<tr><td></td><td></td><td>'+message+'</td></tr>');
                        $('#tabel').load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>ccoba/index'+"#tabel");
                        //reset modal form
                        $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                            $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
 </script>
```

and my question's 
Can i call div element in a view with my controller??

this is my controller :

```
.......
function tabel(){
    $data['hasil'] = $this->mcoba->getAllMessage();
    $this->load->view('tbl_coba',$data); //i want to call div element in a view here
    }
........
```

sorry about my bad english  xD
thnks..

Answer (score 0):

No way to do this. You can create a html file that contains only the div. File HTML may be:

```
<div id="tbl_coba"> Your thing </div>
```

And then you put the filename of your file in:

```
$this->load->view('filename', $data);
```

Or you can modify the framework that you're using to make it satisfying what you want. But It's very complicated. Hope that help.

Comment: ok. in a case i load html file that contains div, success. next question is why when i input data for a second time, bootstrap modal backdrop not disapears??

Comment: Just initiate bootstrap modal again for the div that is loaded after call ajax.

Comment: i use this :                                             success: function(message) {
    $('#input_kategori').modal('toggle');              $('.modal-backdrop').hide(); but modal didn't show again.. i mean modal show  but disapears too fast

Comment: thnks, i found the answer... i change my modal to default bootstrap modal (modal-header, modal-body and modal-footer). Everything Is Working Perfectly

Comment: i think my js is overlapping in my view. now everything Is Working Perfectly